# Dynamic import not working on exported modules typescript

Tags: typescript, deno

i'm working new web framework , do dynamic import don't deserve for default export? so how to do that with default export?

Lol.ts

```
import app from "../trap/app.ts";

//some code

export default app;
```

XD.ts

```
import app from "./lol.ts";

declare global {
    interface Window {
        Log: any;
    }
}

export default class ServiceProvider {
    protected app: any;
    protected log: any;

    constructor(){
        this.app = app;
    }
}
```

WTF.ts

```
import ServiceProvider from "../XD.ts";

export class WTFProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    register(){
        console.log("Register");
        (<any>window).Log = "Greets from register";
    }

    boot(){
        console.log("Boot");
        console.log((<any>window).Log);
    }
}
```

i can't call the WTFProvider in the dynamic import if

Lol.ts

```
constructor(){
    this.app = app;
}
```

but if i delete it

```
constructor(){

}
```

the dynamic import code just basically a basic dynamic import

```
    let filePath = this.providerPath + providerName + '.ts';

    let checkFile = await this.exists(filePath);

    if (checkFile) {
        let importedController = await import("file://" + filePath);
        let provider = new importedController[providerName]();

        this.purpose.push({
            name: provider.constructor.name,
            value: provider
        });
    }else{
        console.log(error("Provider " + providerName + " doesn't exist!"))
    }
```

the dynamic import works!

Comment: Show code to replicate, I don't see any dynamic import in your code.

Comment: let filePath = this.providerPath + providerName + '.ts';
        
            let checkFile = await this.exists(filePath);
        
            if (checkFile) {
                let importedController = await import("file://" + filePath);
                let provider = new importedController[providerName]();
        
                this.purpose.push({
                    name: provider.constructor.name,
                    value: provider
                });
            }else{
                console.log(error("Provider " + providerName + " doesn't exist!"))
            }

Comment: it works when i don't use the default import

Comment: in the target of dynamic impiort

Comment: Update the question with the code please.

Comment: done i alredy aupdated my post